# Can Prozac cause anxiety?

Tags: psychopharmacology, anxiety, serotonin

I know some selective serotonin inhibitors, such as Prozac, are prescribed for anxiety, but can they also cause anxiety?

Comment: Hi, could you perhaps share some initial research you have done yourself already?  Maybe explain a little bit about the SSRI medication with the effects you know about. People will then be better able to estimate what you know and at what level of expertise you would like an answer.

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8415/7604

Answer (score 2):

[Prozac](https://www.drugs.com/prozac.html) (the generic drug [fluoxetine](https://www.drugs.com/fluoxetine.html)) is a [selective serotonin reuptake inhibitor](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/depression/in-depth/ssris/art-20044825) (SSRI) and is primarily prescribed as an **[antidepressant](http://www.webmd.com/depression/ssris-myths-and-facts-about-antidepressants)**, but also as an [anxiolytic](http://www.webmd.com/depression/ssris-myths-and-facts-about-antidepressants).

The side effects of fluoxetine indeed include anxiety, but this is a rare phenomenon (source: [Drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/sfx/prozac-side-effects.html)). The more common complaints are restlessness and skin rash. In fact, [Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/depression/in-depth/ssris/art-20044825?pg=1) doesn't even list anxiety as a general side effect of SSRIs.